# Identity Element of Subtraction (Solution Verification)

Tags: solution-verification

This is about an exercise from Norman L. Biggs *Discrete Mathematics*. One is asked to check which binary operations are valid when $*$ represents the usual $-$ of arithmetic. Now, Biggs says that $-$ has an identity value. But, using the definition:

G3: There is an element $e \in G$ such that $$e*x=x*e=x$$ **for all** $x \in G$. Now, $e-x=x \iff e=2x$ and $x-e=x \iff e=0$. As $2x≠0$ **for all** $x \in G$

I answered that subtraction did not have an identity element. What am I missing?

Comment: It *could* happen that $x+x=0$ for some or even all $x\in G$, but not in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You are not missing anything*.

You are *correct* that there is **no**  *identity element* $\,e\,$ such that for all $\,x\,$ (in most sets), we have that $$e - x = x - e = x.$$

As Federica Maggioni states, "$0$" is a "right-identity" for subtraction, satisfying:

$$\; x - 0 = x,$$ with subtraction defined as we know it.

But this is not an *identity* in the sense that we've defined identity $e \in G$ for a binary operator on $G$: $$e * x = x*e = x$$ for all $x$ in a set $G$ on which $*$ is defined.

Comment: Also deserves a =1

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is neither associative nor commutative, and there is no element $e$ such that for all $x$: $$e -x = x - e = x$$

However, there is a right-identity, namely $0$.